# How To Reenable Bounces and Smooth Scrolling for UIScrollView on tvOS

Tags: uiscrollview, tvos

I have some content that I am placing on a `UIScrollView` on tvOS. I notice that even though I have `bounces` enabled on the scroll view in Interface Builder that my scrolling does not bounce at all.  I have tried setting the bounces programmatically to no avail.  Is this a 'feature' of tvOS?

I have created a subclass of `UIScrollView`, overriding `canBecomeFocused` and setting its `panGestureRecognizer` to allow for `UITouchTypeIndirect`.  This allows for scrolling period.  How do I reenable bounces for `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I am struggling with the same now... Thanks!